# Handling the various permutations of the diff between two lists

Tags: python, list, if-statement, set, list-comprehension

Given two lists `todays_ids` and `baseline_ids`, I will use the following to compile differences between them:

```
    # Status                     added_ids             removed_ids
    # No IDs removed, none added []                    []
    # IDs removed, none added    []                    [id1, id2, ..]
    # IDs added, IDs removed     [id1, id2, ..]        [id1, id2, ..]
    # IDs added, none removed    [id1, id2, ..]        []

    added_ids = [_id for id in todays_ids if _id not in baseline_ids]
    removed_ids = [_id for id in baseline_ids if _id not in todays_ids]
```

I then need to take different actions, depending on which of the the four possible outcomes is the case for any given execution. For simplicity, let's imagine that I need to just print all the relevant ids in each case.

```
if len(added_ids) == 0 and len(removed_ids) > 0
   print 'No new ids'
   print 'The following ids were removed_ids:'
   for _id in removed_ids:
       print _id 

elif len(added_ids) > 0 and len(removed_ids) > 0
   print 'The following ids were added:'
   for _id in added_ids:
       print _id 
   print 'The following ids were removed:'
   for _id in removed_ids:
       print _id 

elif len(added_ids) > 0 and len(removed_ids) == 0
   print 'The following ids were added:'
   for _id in added_ids:
       print _id 
   print 'No ids removed'

else:
    print 'No ids added or removed'
```

Clearly there is some duplicated effort here (perhaps both in the setting up of the diffs with list comprehension, *and* in the subsequent logic), and unnecessarily so. How can it be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
today_ids = ['id1', 'id2', 'id5']
base_line_ids = ['id1','id2','id3','id4']

added_ids = set(today_ids).difference(base_line_ids)
removed_ids = set(base_line_ids).difference(today_ids)

# specific message for: no added, no removed
if set(today_ids) == set(base_line_ids):
    print('No ids added or removed')
    exit(0)

if len(removed_ids):
    print('The following ids were removed:\n{}'.format('\n'.join(removed_ids)))
else:
    print('No ids removed')

if len(added_ids):
    print('The following ids were added:\n{}'.format('\n'.join(added_ids)))
else:
    print('No ids added')
```

Output:

```
The following ids were removed:
id4
id3
The following ids were added:
id5
```

Comment: Killing a multiple of `n` birds with `n` stones. Nicely done.

Comment: Still i needed two times less stones, compared to your approach... ;)

Comment: The original had a specific message if no ids were added or removed; this does not.

Comment: @ScottHunter, thank you for pointing that out! I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the sum of the lengths are both 0, say so; otherwise for each list, say either it is empty or list its contents.

Comment: Can the downvoter please provide a comment, so we can all learn something.

Answer (score 1):

```
added_ids = set(today_ids).difference(set(baseline_ids))
removed_ids = set(baseline_ids).difference(set(today_ids))

if added_ids:
    if removed_ids:
        do_something
    else:
        do_something
else:
    if removed_ids:
        do_something
    else:
        do_something
```

Comment: Yes, it has. Look at the last line.